# Extracting the (x,y,z) coordinates from pointcloud2 data in Python

Tags: python, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm in the process of using a stereo camera that generates a pointcloud2  sensor message. I can open it up in rviz, and view the pointcloud. now I want to try and use the uint8[] data for a system I'm working on. I have a Python subscription node that can subscribe to the proper topic as well as print the data inside the script. I just need to know how to get from this huge data string to a useable (x, y, z) format or numpy array in camera space for me to do something useful for it.

I did stumble across python-pcl by strawlab, but I'm not sure if that's what I need to use, or what?

Looking forward to some help!

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230680/extracting-the-(x,y,z)-coordinates-from-pointcloud2-data-in-python/) by [atomoclast](https://answers.ros.org/users/26451/atomoclast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/202787/using-pointcloud2-data-getting-xy-points-in-python/

http://ros-by-example.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rbx_vol_1/rbx1_apps/nodes/follower2.py

```
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2
...
for point in sensor_msgs.point_cloud2.read_points(msg, skip_nans=True):
            pt_x = point[0]
            pt_y = point[1]
            pt_z = point[2]
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-03-22**:
I belive x y and z cordinates are not same with the frame of the Camera, I am using this lines of code as below:

```
    number_of_sampling = 30
    x_total = 0
    y_total = 0
    z_total = 0
    counter = 0
    
    for point in sensor_msgs.point_cloud2.read_points(data, skip_nans=True):

        y_total += point[0]
        z_total += point[1]
        x_total += point[2]
##        print x_total, y_total, z_total      
        counter += 1
        if counter == number_of_sampling: break

    x_average = x_total / number_of_sampling
    y_average = -1*y_total / number_of_sampling
    z_average = -1*z_total / number_of_sampling
```

In other words 0 index is Y 1st index is Z and 2nd index is X

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know I'm a little late here, but a function is included in ros_numpy package for this exact purpose.
http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ros_numpy/html/point__cloud2_8py_source.html

An example implementation:

```
import ros_numpy
...
xyz_array = ros_numpy.point_cloud2.get_xyz_points(pointcloud2_array)
```

---

Originally posted by [saltus](https://answers.ros.org/users/37231/saltus/) with karma: 131 on 2018-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6